# How to real value for int from json

Tags: java, android, json, web-services

In my project I have an `int jsonobject` by 20 value. To get the `int` value I used this:

```
model.setInt(jsonObject.getInt("price"));
```

Now it returns 0 value for price. How can I get real value?

Here is My out put Json:

```
      "data": [
    {
      "id": "571dd7817f8b9a1c190bbdb5",
      "goods": 0,
      "rate": {
        "r1": 0
      },
      "price": 20
     }
```

Comment: please print stack trace..!

Comment: could you show us the `JSON`?

Comment: It looks like part of your problem may be the misspelling in 'jsonObjest' where you probably meant to write 'jsonObject'?

Comment: please post your json Structure. and which library u used to fetch Data from `JSON`

Comment: Also check your KEY value i.e "price". It should be case sensitive.

Comment: In log cat i see correct data but when when i want to print it just 0 will be print.

Comment: @BlakeYarbrough I posted my json

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the example:

```
String jsonData = "{\"count\": 20}";
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
System.out.println("Count: " + obj.getInt("count"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `JSON` is invalid. you can use online tools like the [jsonformatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to test the validity of your `JSON`.

Maybe try something like:

```
{
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "571dd7817f8b9a1c190bbdb5",
        "goods": 0,
        "rate": {"r1": 0},
        "price": 20
      }
    ]
}
```

Looking at your code, you may have better luck with this structure:

```
{
    "id": "571dd7817f8b9a1c190bbdb5",
    "goods": 0,
    "rate": {"r1": 0},
    "price": 20
}
```

Comment: I post a part of my json. It is correct because i can get rate and goods but just in price value i have problem

Comment: Can you post your *whole class* and *entire* `JSON`? Otherwise it's going to be impossible to help.